# Generic-класс, наследуемый от Exception

Tags: компилятор, java

Для передачи какого-либо объекта через исключения, я написал Generic-класс, наследуемый от Exception, но компилятор говорит, что generic-класс не может быть унаследован от java.lang.Throwable. Вот код класса:

```
public class ObjectException<O extends Object>extends Exception {
    private O object;
    public ObjectException(O object)throws NullPointerException{
        if(object!=null)this.object=object; else throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    public O getObject(){
        return this.object;
    }
    static public <O extends Object> void throwObject(O object)throws ObjectException{
        throw new ObjectException<O>(object);
    }
    public void throwObject()throws ObjectException<O>{
        throw this;
    }
    static public <O extends Object> ObjectException<O> getException(O object){
        return new ObjectException<O>(object);
    }
    public ObjectException<O> getException(){
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ObjectException with object:"+this.object.toString();
    }

}
```

Можно ли как-нибудь обойти это ограничение или реализовать эту идею как-нибудь по-другому?

Comment: > Для передачи какого-либо объекта через исключения

Но зачем? И зачем для этого дженерик, разве просто конструктор с Object в качестве параметра не сработает?

Answer (score 3):

С формальной точки зрения, нельзя, так как запрещено спецификацией языка, точка.

С неформальной точки зрения, мотивация следующая. Вспомните, что дженерики в Java — конструкция времени компиляции, не существующая во время выполнения. Это значит, что в рантайме нет никакой разницы между `ObjectException<String>` и `ObjectException<Integer>`. И `catch` тоже не сможет их различить.

Поэтому код

```
try {
   ObjectException<Integer>.throwObject(42);
} catch (ObjectException<String> ex) {
   String s = ex.GetObject();
}
```

вылетит из-за неправильного преобразования типов, при попытке привести `Integer` к `String`!

Comment: Но ведь можно было бы сделать так:

     try {
        ObjectException<Integer>.throwObject(42);
     } catch (ObjectException<String> ex) {
        try{
           String s = ex.GetObject();
        } catch(ClassCastException e){}
     }

Comment: И да, кстати, 42 не является экземпляром класса Integer. Чтобы создать экземпляр класса Integer со значением 42, нужно было вызвать конструктор

     new Integer(42);

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей Если вы собираетесь ловить ClassCastException, то зачем вам дженерики?

Ну и про 42: autoboxing сделает это за вас, при условии, что компилятор сможет вывести тип аргумента.

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей: Проблема в том, что по коду **не видно**, что нужны такое танцы с бубном. А значит, программисты **будут** ошибаться. Зачем нужна такая фича, которая провоцирует ошибки?